# immutable strict ignored by plv8 function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plv8

I thought immutable strict ment the database could not be modified.

The following inserts a new row in 'some_table':

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_row() RETURNS void AS
$$
  plv8.execute('INSERT INTO some_table (number) VALUES ($1)', [123]);
$$
LANGUAGE plv8 IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Is it not possible to prevent a function modifying the database?

Comment: The [volatility category](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-volatility.html) of a function is mostly a promise your function makes to PostrgreSQL, your function can lie but you shouldn't expect anything good to come of it.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for me.

If I execute something like:

```
select insert_row() from some_OTHER_table;
```

I get EXACTLY one new row in some_table regardless of the number of rows in some_other_table.

If you don't want your function modifies your database, simply DON'T put insert or update statements in it.

Comment: I only tryed to help. (Sorry for that).
As you noticed, I can't comment (I don't understand why if I can answer...) but you're right. Maybe this could be better inserted as a comment (as I can't do).

Sorry again for trying to help.